# Software for handling graphs in Python or C/C++

Tags: python, c++, graphs, c

I am looking for some package that handles graphs in python or C or C++. There are quite a few out there, as found in Google. But that is why I come here...

Handling graphic representations and stats is a plus, of course.

I would likely not need to develop/implement algoithms, etc. But I would most likely need to modify code to suit my needs, in minor aspects.

Any recommendation?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "handles graphs"? And are you looking to develop something on your own, or something for end-users?

Comment: @einpoklum - As of now, I am not certain about the reach of my work. If a definition is demanded, I would say that I am an end-user at this point.

Comment: You have to edit your question to say that, and to give at least one concrete example of what you intend to be doing. Also, if you're an end user - why would you care about the language?

Comment: @einpoklum - End-user means for me that I would likely not need to develop/implement algoithms, etc. But I would most likely need to modify code to suit my needs, in minor aspects.

Answer (score 3):

To handle [graphs data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) in Python there is the popular [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/).

Another simpler and effective library is [Altgraph](https://pythonhosted.org/altgraph/) (that I use and contribute to)

Comment: I have found NetworkX, and it seems to be somewhat popular. Do you have any comments, on pros and cons, maturity, etc.? Same for Altgraph.

Comment: It is full featured. Never a bad choice. I preferred altgraph for simpler hacking

Answer (score 2):

I code both Python & C++ (and a few others), and I eschew drag & drop, GUI based, tools in favour of those which take their input from a text file. That makes it easy for me to develop programs to generate the input text file from my own data.

You may not want to do that, but it is still worthwhile looking at [GraphViz](http://graphviz.org/).

As an example:

```
graph { 
    a -- b; 
    b -- c; 
    a -- c; 
    d -- c; 
    e -- c; 
    e -- a; 
}
```

generates
[image]

Obviously, it can produce much more complex diagrams that that, but that shows the principle - a simple text language to describe the relationship between nodes.

Take a look at their [gallery](http://graphviz.org/Gallery.php) to see how powerful it is.

GraphViz has been around for a long time, is well supported, has an active forum and is widely used in academia and in some popular tools like DoxyGen.

Answer (score 1):

[SNAP (Stanford Network Analysis Platform)](http://snap.stanford.edu/index.html) is [a C++ library](http://snap.stanford.edu/snap/index.html) for the processing and analysis of graphs and networks.  There is also [a Python wrapper](http://snap.stanford.edu/snappy/index.html).  From the SNAP website:

> Stanford Network Analysis Platform (SNAP) is a general purpose, high
>   performance system for analysis and manipulation of large networks.
>   Graphs consists of nodes and directed/undirected/multiple edges
>   between the graph nodes. Networks are graphs with data on nodes and/or
>   edges of the network.
>
> The core SNAP library is written in C++ and optimized for maximum
>   performance and compact graph representation. It easily scales to
>   massive networks with hundreds of millions of nodes, and billions of
>   edges. It efficiently manipulates large graphs, calculates structural
>   properties, generates regular and random graphs, and supports
>   attributes on nodes and edges. Besides scalability to large graphs, an
>   additional strength of SNAP is that nodes, edges and attributes in a
>   graph or a network can be changed dynamically during the computation.